# shared-ptr map with lldb pretty printers

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, lldb, stdmap

I have a std::map where I am using shared_ptrs as keys:

```
std::map<shared_ptr<object>, shared_ptr<object>>
```

However, when debugging, I am unable to open these maps using lldb on macOS or gdb on linux. With gdb this issue was fixed on Ubuntu by modifying the file libstdcxx/v6/printers.py and adding iterators to the SharedPointerPrinter class (code shown below). However, I don't know how to fix this issue for lldb. If anyone can help me or point me in the right direction that would be great.

Please let me know if you need other information in order to help me solve this issue and I will happily provide it.

```
class SharedPointerPrinter:
    "Print a shared_ptr or weak_ptr"

    class _iterator:
        def __init__(self, sharedPointer):
            self.sharedPointer = sharedPointer
            self.managedValue = sharedPointer.val['_M_ptr']
            self.count = 0

        def __iter__(self):
            return self

        def next(self):
            if self.managedValue == 0:
                raise StopIteration
            self.count = self.count + 1
            if (self.count == 1):
                return ('Use count', self.sharedPointer.val['_M_refcount']['_M_pi']['_M_use_count'])
            elif (self.count == 2):
                return ('Weak count', self.sharedPointer.val['_M_refcount']['_M_pi']['_M_weak_count'] - 1)
            elif (self.count == 3):
                return ('Managed value', self.managedValue)
            else:
                raise StopIteration

    def __init__ (self, typename, val):
        self.typename = typename
        self.val = val

    def children (self):
        return self._iterator(self)

    def to_string (self):
        state = 'empty'
        refcounts = self.val['_M_refcount']['_M_pi']
        if refcounts != 0:
            usecount = refcounts['_M_use_count']
            weakcount = refcounts['_M_weak_count']
            if usecount == 0:
                state = 'expired, weakcount %d' % weakcount
            else:
                state = 'usecount %d, weakcount %d' % (usecount, weakcount - 1)
        return '%s (%s) to %s' % (self.typename, state, self.val['_M_ptr'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do pretty much the same thing using lldb's Python data formatters as described on this page:

http://lldb.llvm.org/varformats.html

lldb has data formatters for std::map and std::shared_ptr for clang's version of STL.  So for instance, I see:

```
(lldb) fr v a_map
(std::__1::map<std::__1::shared_ptr<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, std::__1::shared_ptr<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, std::__1::less<std::__1::shared_ptr<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const std::__1::shared_ptr<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, std::__1::shared_ptr<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > > >) a_map = size=1 {
  [0] = {
    first = "some text" strong=2 weak=1 {
      __ptr_ = "some text"
    }
    second = "other text" strong=2 weak=1 {
      __ptr_ = "other text"
    }
  }
}
```

Man, those C++ types are verbose!

There are also some formatters for the gcc's STL but I don't know as much about the state of those formatters.

IIUC the data formatters can be used in expressions in gdb.  In lldb, the `frame variable` command will accept simple structure access expressions, so you can do:

```
(lldb) frame var a_map[0].first
(const std::__1::shared_ptr<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >) a_map[0].first = "some text" strong=2 weak=1 {
  __ptr_ = "some text"
}
```

But you can't use the data formatter produced children in the full expression parser.